# React Formik checkbox condition based value remove in other Fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am using `react-formik` for form I have one issue with checkbox based condition, the check relation to another two fields if user checked the hidden fields are showing else it's hidden, the user unchecked the remaining two contains values, but I want if user unchecked all fields to empty.

My code:

[image: Edit ConditionCheck]

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you want to control the value of one field based on the value of other field you can make use of the `setFieldValue` provided by Formik.

The `Field` components has a render prop which is a function and which helps us to access the `setFieldValue` in its argument. Now with the `setFieldValue` being accessible you can use it set the value of the dependent fields when the checkbox is checked or unChecked.

You need to render the Field component for your checkbox as below

```
<Field
  name="airconditioning"
  render={({ meta, form }) => {
    return (
      <Checkbox
        checked={meta.value}
        onChange={(e) => {
          const { checked } = e.target;
          if (!checked) {
            form.setFieldValue("airconditioningType", "");
            form.setFieldValue("airconditioningStarred", "");
          }
          form.setFieldValue("airconditioning", checked || "");
        }}
        name="checkedB"
        color="primary"
      />
    );
  }}
/>
```

[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/conditioncheck-forked-z1316?file=/src/App.js)